# swipebox img base64 without attr a

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I make a swipebox. without [a] attributes. Only on img. It doesn't work for me for some reason.
If you advise any other library for opening a photo, working in my situation would be grateful. Thanks

```js
;( function( $ ) {

    $( '.swipebox' ).swipebox();

} )( jQuery );
```

```html
<script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swipebox@1.4.6/lib/ios-orientationchange-fix.min.js "></script>
<link href=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swipebox@1.4.6/src/css/swipebox.min.css " rel="stylesheet">
<script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.min.js "></script>

<div>
  <div>
    <img class="swipebox" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery should be before the swipebox.js :

The `ios-orientationchange-fix.min.js` that you are using is just a fix for ios not included the swipebox itself.

```js
( function( $ ) {

    $( '.swipebox' ).swipebox();

} )( jQuery );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.swipebox/1.4.4/js/jquery.swipebox.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swipebox@1.4.6/src/css/swipebox.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div>
  <div>
    <img class="swipebox" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="image">
  </div>
</div>
```